# Hadoop Exception: All specified directories are failed to load

Tags: hadoop, terminal

When I started the Hadoop cluster, the following Exception was thrown. I dont't have idea for solving it. Anyone help me. Thanks

```
2017-07-10 09:40:58,960 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /tools/hadoop/hadoop_storage/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-47191263-b5b7-4a4d-b8b5-a78b782e66bb; datanode clusterID = CID-79a53373-9652-4c08-9735-b5972e0450ca
2017-07-10 09:40:58,960 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-07-10 09:40:58,961 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310
2017-07-10 09:40:58,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
2017-07-10 09:41:00,962 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2017-07-10 09:41:00,964 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
2017-07-10 09:41:00,966 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It perhaps you format your cluster one more time thus it generate different ID cluster in the master node and data node.
Your namenode and datanode cluster ID does not match and you make sure to make them the same.
In name node, change cluster id in the file located in:

```
$ nano HADOOP_FILE_SYSTEM/namenode/current/VERSION
```

In data node you cluster id is stored in the file:

```
$ nano HADOOP_FILE_SYSTEM/datanode/current/VERSION
```

Whatever the way you change ID, but assure that the ID in the cluster's nodes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

@VanThaoNguyen is correct

In my case:
/*installation directory*/hdata/dfs/name/current
/*installation directory*/hdata/dfs/data/current

****clusterID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx****

should be same for name node and data node.